# Read a text file using SQLNCLI

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, openrowset

I want to read a text (in this case, csv) from a file. I'm not trying to bulk-load for now, simply read.

As far as I can tell, only the SQLNCLI provider is available.

Ad Hoc Distributed Queries are enabled (value_in_use = 1 for `select * from sys.configurations where name like '%ad hoc Dis%'`)

```sql
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
'server=localhost;trusted_connection=yes;
Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
data source=\\valid\path\to\my\folder\Test.csv;
Extensions=csv;HDR=yes;FMT=Delimited',
'SELECT * FROM [Test.csv]'
) AS data;
```

I get this error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".
>
> Invalid object name 'Test.csv'.

What am I doing wrong? Is [Test.csv] the right way to reference the file?

Using:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: This has a number of potential solutions to the "Deferred prepare could not be completed" error. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15158017/10592356 Maybe one of them applies to your case.

Comment: Have you tried using the BULK subcommand of OPENROWSET? That can be used to read, not just to do a bulk import.